# Display Json on gridview and listview with specific condition

Tags: c#, json, listview, gridview, uwp

I have json shown in gridview. In the gridview displays the title and when clicked will appear a listview that takes data from json on the xfile array.
JSON:

```
{
    "error": false,
    "total_data": 94,
    "data_per_page": "20",
    "total_page": 5,
    "current_total": 20,
    "tipe": "Video",
    "data": [
        {
            "judul": "Kelas 01 Bab 02 Tematik Mengenal Bagian Tubuh",
            "fname": "Kelas_01_Bab_02_Tematik_Mengenal_Bagian_Tubuh.mp4",
            "xfile": [
                {
                    "url": "http://10.26.0.100:8080/video/SD_1/Kelas_01_Bab_02_Tematik_Mengenal_Bagian_Tubuh.mp4",
                    "ukuran": 33295148,
                    "formated_size": "31.75M",
                    "res": "hd"
                },
                {
                    "url": "NOT EXIST",
                    "ukuran": 0,
                    "formated_size": "0.00B",
                    "res": "med"
                },
                {
                    "url": "http://10.26.0.100:8080/video/SD_1/converted/Kelas_01_Bab_02_Tematik_Mengenal_Bagian_Tubuh_320x180.mp4",
                    "ukuran": 8278244,
                    "formated_size": "7.89M",
                    "res": "low"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "judul": "Kelas 01 Bab 04 Agama Islam Bersih Itu Sehat",
            "fname": "Kelas_01_Bab_04_Agama_Islam_Bersih_Itu_Sehat.mp4",
            "xfile": [
                {
                    "url": "http://10.26.0.100:8080/video/SD_1/Kelas_01_Bab_04_Agama_Islam_Bersih_Itu_Sehat.mp4",
                    "ukuran": 56111407,
                    "formated_size": "53.51M",
                    "res": "hd"
                },
                {
                    "url": "NOT EXIST",
                    "ukuran": 0,
                    "formated_size": "0.00B",
                    "res": "med"
                },
                {
                    "url": "http://10.26.0.100:8080/video/SD_1/converted/Kelas_01_Bab_04_Agama_Islam_Bersih_Itu_Sehat_320x180.mp4",
                    "ukuran": 11351698,
                    "formated_size": "10.83M",
                    "res": "low"
                }
            ]
        },
```

Code:

```
ObservableCollection<Video> datasource = new ObservableCollection<Video>();
ObservableCollection<XFile> data = new ObservableCollection<XFile>();    
try
    {
        loading.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        busyindicator.IsActive = true;
        string urlPath1 = kelas.Link;
        var httpClient1 = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());

        var values1 = 
            new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("halaman", noHal.ToString()),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("limit", limit.ToString())
            };

        var response1 = await httpClient1.PostAsync(urlPath1, new FormUrlEncodedContent(values1));
        response1.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        if (!response1.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            busyindicator.IsActive = false;
            RequestException();
        }
        string jsonText1 = await response1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        JsonObject jsonObject1 = JsonObject.Parse(jsonText1);
        JsonArray jsonData1 = jsonObject1["data"].GetArray();

        foreach (JsonValue groupValue1 in jsonData1)
        {
            JsonObject groupObject2 = groupValue1.GetObject();

            string title = groupObject2["judul"].GetString();
            string cover = groupObject2.ContainsKey("cover") && groupObject2["cover"] != null ? groupObject2["cover"].GetString() : string.Empty;
            string fname = groupObject2["fname"].GetString();

            Video file1 = new Video();
            file1.Judul = title;
            file1.Cover = cover;
            file1.FName = fname;

            JsonArray pathJson = groupObject2["xfile"].GetArray();\
            foreach (JsonValue groupValue2 in pathJson)
            {
                JsonObject groupObject3 = groupValue2.GetObject();
                string url = groupObject3["url"].GetString();
                string size = groupObject3["formated_size"].GetString();
                string resolution = groupObject3["res"].GetString();
                XFile file2 = new XFile();
                file2.URL = url;
                file2.Size = size;
                file2.Resolution = resolution;
                data.Add(file2);
            }

            datasource.Add(file1);
        }

        itemGridView.ItemsSource = datasource;

    //...

    private async void ItemView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        AvaibleRes.IsOpen = true;
        Video item = e.ClickedItem as Video;
        DetailJudul.Text = item.Judul;
        ResolutionList.ItemsSource = data;
    }

    private void ResolutionList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ResolutionList.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            XFile res = e.AddedItems[0] as XFile;
            DetailURL.Text = res.URL;
        }
    }
```

Video:

```
public class Video
{
    public string Judul { get; set; }
    public string FName { get; set; }
}
```

XFile:

```
public class XFile
{
    public string URL { get; set; }

        public string Size { get; set; }

        public string Resolution { get; set; }
}
```

I have a problem, namely: after clicking on gridview, the listview displays all xfile data. I want to click, for example: Class 01 Chapter 02 Thematic Knowing the Body Parts, then the data displayed in the listview is only xfile on that data only.
How to handle it?

Comment: what's the `datasource`? its list of object or datatable or any else?

Comment: ObservableCollection<Video> datasource = new ObservableCollection<Video>();
        ObservableCollection<XFile> data = new ObservableCollection<XFile>();

Comment: did u successfully get `Video item = e.ClickedItem as Video;` value in item?

Comment: I tried debugging and the item.title is successfully to read

Comment: try this `private async void ItemView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            AvaibleRes.IsOpen = true;
            Video item = e.ClickedItem as Video;
            DetailJudul.Text = item.Judul;

            var result = datasource.Where(x => x.Judul == item.Judul).Select(x => new XFile { URL = x.URL, Size = x.Size, Resolution = x.Resolution }).ToList();

            ResolutionList.ItemsSource = result;
        }`

Comment: @ershoaib I have tried the code above, but the ResolutionList was not successfully displayed and blank

Comment: try to add brekpoint on `var result` and show me the values contains in

Comment: @ershoaib null because the datasource is only available (in the video class), while the resolution and size are in the XFile class and are displayed in ResolutionList

Comment: ok let me add answer for you. If you find well then you can implement on your side :)

Comment: could you plz provide me the sample value in `string jsonText1`?

Comment: "judul": "Kelas 03 Bab 01 IPA Bumi Bagian dari Alam Semesta" "fname": "Kelas_03_Bab_01_IPA_Bumi_Bagian_dari_Alam_Semesta.mp4" Like this image: https://postimg.cc/7fcN4mJx

Comment: I tried debugging and x.title = item.title was read successfully, while x.url etc. was not readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all try to create quick type for your json.

```
public class Xfile
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public int ukuran { get; set; }
    public string formated_size { get; set; }
    public string res { get; set; }
}

public class video
{
    public string judul { get; set; }
    public string fname { get; set; }
    public string cover { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Xfile> xfile { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public bool error { get; set; }
    public int total_data { get; set; }
    public string data_per_page { get; set; }
    public int total_page { get; set; }
    public int current_total { get; set; }
    public string tipe { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public ObservableCollection<video> videos { get; set; }
}
```

Then below code deserialize your json to your quick type by using `Newtonsoft.json`

```
ObservableCollection<Video> datasource = new ObservableCollection<Video>();
ObservableCollection<XFile> data = new ObservableCollection<XFile>();    
try
    {
       //Your code here

       string jsonText1 = await response1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
       RootObject rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonText1);

       itemGridView.ItemsSource = rootObject.videos.Select(x => new video { fname = x.fname, judul = x.judul, cover = x.cover }).ToList();   

       //Your code here        
    }
```

In your `ItemView_ItemClick`.

```
private async void ItemView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    AvaibleRes.IsOpen = true;
    video item = e.ClickedItem as video;
    DetailJudul.Text = item.judul;
    ResolutionList.ItemsSource = rootObject.videos.Where(x => x.judul == item.Judul)
                                                  .SelectMany(x => x.xfile).ToList();
}
```

**Note:** Make `RootObject rootObject = new RootObject();` object globally so you can access it through across multiple method or events.

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Rose, view the answer might be it help you :)

Comment: I have tried your code and gridview can be displayed, but when gridview is clicked an error message appears: https://postimg.cc/bs46J79s I have already declared RootObject rootObject = new RootObject(); globally

Comment: add breakpoint and check once again is there `item.Judal` contains value or not? if yes then  check is there values inside `rootObject.videos` and let me know

Comment: ok first we solve your first exception in previous image, so add breakpoint in `ResolutionList.ItemsSource= ` line and give me data inside `rootObject.videos` so I'll try to figure out why this error comes => value cannot be null

Comment: Now there is no error message, but ResolutionList is blank and I have another problem, namely for gridview using halaman (page) and limit parameters and I set the limit to 20 per page. The problem is that the one shown on the gridview is only the last 20 data

Comment: please check once if there is `xfile` available for your particular `item.Judal`. If no then `ResolutionList` will be blank

Comment: After I check in your code there is nothing to declare the contents of xfile (URL, Size, and Resolution). Where should be put?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180720/discussion-between-ershoaib-and-rose).

Comment: I will go home from the office. What if we continue to chat tomorrow?

Comment: lets continue in chat. click on above comment link

Comment: see here i suceessfully get 3 xfile on my side for your `item.Judal` => `Kelas 01 Tema 4 Subtema 2 Matematika Menghitung Loncat Video Pendidikan Indonesia` https://postimg.cc/JyhmQLhN

Comment: plz provide me your `Xfile` class (that is quick type in my answer). i have to check its properties

Comment: public class XFile
    {
        public string URL { get; set; }
        public string Size { get; set; }
        public string Resolution { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Try all my classes in answer as it is, bcoz your json has all keys are in small and your xfile  class properties are in caps. So it doesnt match and gives you null values, try my classes as it is, if you want to change property names to yours, then I'll let you know how to do it, but first try my  suggestion and let me know

Comment: Done. Thank you for your help